# Calculate height of bar in pixels from a Y value in D3 graph

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js

I have a quick question. I am trying to determine the height in pixels of a chart bar. This is for a D3 implementation, and my chart has a logarithmic y-axis.

1. I know the Y value for the bar I am trying to plot.
2. I also know the height of the axis in pixels (600px).
3. I know the min and the max of the Y-axis

I have tried various computations but cannot seem to calculate the height of the bar so that it connects the Y value with the x-Axis.

The picture below should provide a visual illustration of what I am trying to do. Right now I can't seem to get it right ... I think this is essentially a problem in maths, not so much D3. Thank you!

*** EDIT ****

This is the y axis scale that I am using:

```
var y = d3.scale.log()
.range([height, 0])
.domain([d3.min(sampleData, function(d) {
      return d.y;
    }),
    d3.max(sampleData, function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
  ]);
```

[image]

Comment: That smells like a XY problem to me (no pun intended). Anyway, are you using a scale? If so,  it easily gives you the height of the bar. Please post *your math*, so we can have a better idea of what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Hello Gerardo, pleasure to hear from you again. Yes, I am using a scale: var y = d3.scale.log()

Comment: Hello Noobster. So, if you're using a scale, why don't you pass the value of the bar to get its height?

Comment: Appreciate this sounds stupid -but how do you do that?

Comment: Again, I'm not sure of what you're trying to do here, but if you have a scale with a domain going from 0 to a maximum value, and a range going from range[0] to range[1], just call the scale for the value you want and subtract range[0] from the result.

Comment: I will paste my scale information in the question so you can see what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure about your problem, because the actual height of the bar is being calculated by the very scale you use to append the rectangles. And, if you're in fact appending the rectangles, you're already setting the `height` attribute!

Let's see an example. This is a bar chart using your log scale (I'm using D3 v4 here, but the principle is the same) and this fake data:

```
var data = [2000, 5000, 3000, 8000, 1500];
```

As you can see, there is a minimum and a maximum. I put a padding of 20px in the scale:

```
var yScale = d3.scaleLog()
    .range([height - padding, padding])
    .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)]);
```

So, our first value in the range is `h - padding` and our last value is just `padding`. Here is the chart:

```js
var width = 300,
  height = 400,
  padding = 20;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var data = [2000, 5000, 3000, 8000, 1500];

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([50, width])
  .domain(d3.range(data.length))
  .padding(0.2);

var yScale = d3.scaleLog()
  .range([height - padding, padding])
  .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)]);

var bars = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i))
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", d => height - padding - yScale(d))
  .attr("y", d => yScale(d))
  .attr("fill", "teal");

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - padding) + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Suppose you want to calculate the height of the first bar. We can see, by inspecting the DOM, that its height is `61.867984771728516` pixels:

```js
var width = 300,
  height = 400,
  padding = 20;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var data = [2000, 5000, 3000, 8000, 1500];

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([50, width])
  .domain(d3.range(data.length))
  .padding(0.2);

var yScale = d3.scaleLog()
  .range([height - padding, padding])
  .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)]);

var bars = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i))
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", d => height - padding - yScale(d))
  .attr("y", d => yScale(d))
  .attr("fill", "teal");

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - padding) + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
  
console.log(d3.select("rect").node().height.animVal.value)
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

But this is simply the first value in the range (`height - padding`) minus `yScale(2000)`:

```js
var width = 300,
  height = 400,
  padding = 20;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var data = [2000, 5000, 3000, 8000, 1500];

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([50, width])
  .domain(d3.range(data.length))
  .padding(0.2);

var yScale = d3.scaleLog()
  .range([height - padding, padding])
  .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)]);

var bars = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i))
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", d => height - padding - yScale(d))
  .attr("y", d => yScale(d))
  .attr("fill", "teal");

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - padding) + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

console.log(height - padding - yScale(2000))
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Which, by the way, is the value used to set the height of the bars:

```
.attr("height", d => height - padding - yScale(d))
```

Comment: Embarrassingly I forgot that with D3 we are working from the top left corner which is still counter-intuitive for me. The key to your answer is that we need to substract the height of the bar from the height of the plot area. Thank you so much Gerardo.

Comment: No worries! But this has nothing to do with D3: this is the SVG specification (btw, canvas is also the same), putting the origin at the top left corner.

Comment: Thanks again. As always, the clue is in my name :)